# How to return specific fields from a JSON object array in angular http service as response

Tags: json, angular, dictionary, pipe, response

My Interface is like this:

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Response i received from api is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv"
  }
]
```

I wish to extract only id and name fields and return as response

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell"
  }
]
```

```
getdata(): Observable<User[]>{
   return this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
     map((data: User[])=> {
       //how to extract id and name here
     })
   )
}
```

I need to return only id and name fields from
the whole api response. How can i achieve that using map
or any other techniques inside service, Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getdata(): Observable<User[]>{ 
 return this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').pipe(
  map((data: User[])=> {
   //  just map the data 
   return data.map(u => ({id: u.id, name: u.name}))
  })
 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, but it is returning undefined as it is an object of array. However, i have tried your method like so
return data.map(u => ({id: u[0].id, name: u[0].name}))
and it returns desired result, but only the first record of index zero. How can i get all records, can you please suggest

Comment: you need to check what the response actually is and transform it correctly. for the jsonplaceholder response, what i have in my answer is correct.

Comment: Finally solved it, data returning from api should not be of User[] type, May be we shall have to create another interface for the incoming data or use 'any'. Response returned should only be of User[] type

made little change
return this.http.get<any>
now it is working ok, Thanks